# How to combine 2 vectors using element-wise multiplication training in Keras functional API?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, layer

I’m a beginner in Keras. I meet a simple problem, but I have searched for a long time and cannot find how to deal with it.

In briefly, I have 2 vectors: `[a1, a2, a3]` & `[b1, b2, b3]`, and I want to combine them by giving their weights, using the following formula to get the new vector: `[y1, y2, y3]`. Then how to implement this with Keras?

[formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKNsc.png)

My situation is that: I build 2 models separately, and each one has its prediction output (i.e. 3 values representing the predicted value of 3 categories). The output of the first model is `[a1, a2, a3]`, and for the second model is `[b1, b2, b3]`.

Now I want to merge these 2 outputs to get new prediction results `[y1, y2, y3]`, so `y1` is the combination of `a1` & `b1`, and the model should learn the weight by itself. It means that `y1 = w1*a1 + w4*b1`, and `w1` and `w4` are the weights to be trained. Similarly, `y2 = w2*a2 + w5*b2`, `y3 = w3*a3 + w6*b3`, so I have 6 weights to be trained. It is like element-wise multiplication, but the numbers being multiplication are the weights to be trained. I have tried the following codes, but I find that it’s not what I want.

```py
# output_a & output_b are size (3,1)
merge = concatenate([output_a, output_b], axis=2)
# merge is (3,2)
output_y = Dense(1, use_bias=False)(merge)
# output_y is (3,1)
```

I find that in the Dense layer, the number of training parameter is 2. I think it means that it just has 2 weights (i.e. `w1=w2=w3`, and `w4=w5=w6`). I’m not sure how to fix it. Thank you all for helping me!

Edit: Someone told me that maybe I should define the layer I want by myself. So isn't there any function I can use to achieve that?

Edit: I add a figure below and I think it can describe my question.

[A figure that describes my question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqjY3.png)

Comment: weights learned from what ?

Comment: I'm building a neural network, so the weights are learned from training data.

Answer (score 1):

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense,multiply,add
from keras.models import Model

output_a = Input(shape=(3,))
output_b = Input(shape=(3,))
weights_a = Dense(3,use_bias=False)(output_a)
weights_b = Dense(3,use_bias=False)(output_b)
a_weighted = multiply([output_a,weights_a])
b_weighted = multiply([output_b,weights_b])
output_y = add([a_weighted,b_weighted])
```

weights learned from self input

Comment: Thanks for responding. But I think in your codes, there're 3*3+3*3=18 weights to be trained, right? I want to assign only 6 weights. I have edited my post and added a figure to describe my question. Kindly have a look at the picture, thanks!

Comment: Dense Layer produce a 3 weight values

Comment: Do you mean that I can create the "fictitious" weights, weights_a & weights_b, to be the training weights of vector a & b? I'm thinking whether it is equivalent to my problem. For example, actually each element in weights_a (`w1`, `w2` & `w3`) are calculated from `a1`, `a2` & `a3`, although it will just times its corresponding value to get the final prediction result. (e.g. `w1` times `a1` to get `y1`)

Comment: The weights are learned from training data. For instance:
`a = Input(shape=(3,))`
`b = Dense(3, use_bias=False)(a)`
`model = Model(inputs=a, outputs=b)`
It means that I can use training data to train the weights of fully-connected layer between `a` and `b` to get the best prediction result. And it has nine weights to learned by itself. The weights are from the connections between the neurons, so I don't have to  create the "weight" like `weights_a`.

Comment: I just find the solution of my question in other post here: [Custom connections between layers Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47265412/custom-connections-between-layers-keras) It describes how to customize the connections (weights) between the layers.