# keras custom connection and activation function trainable parameters

Tags: keras

I would like to write a network with custom connection and custom activation functions for some channels. Check the figure.

[image]

let's say:  10 hidden-layers and 128 channels. Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47265412/custom-connections-between-layers-keras) I have tried the next:

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Input, Concatenate, Lambda

inputTensor = Input((3,))
```

ss

```
group1 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,0:1], output_shape=((1,)))(inputTensor)
group2 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,0:1], output_shape=((1,)))(inputTensor)
group3 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,1:2], output_shape=((1,)))(inputTensor)
group4 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,1:2], output_shape=((1,)))(inputTensor)
group5 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,2:], output_shape=((1,)))(inputTensor)
group6 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,2:], output_shape=((1,)))(inputTensor)
```

for the second layer:

```
xsin = Dense(1,activation=sin_activation,use_bias=True)
group1 = xsin(group1)
xcos = Dense(1,activation=cos_activation,use_bias=True)
group2 = xcos(group2)
ysin = Dense(1,activation=sin_activation,use_bias=True)
group3 = ysin(group3)
ycos = Dense(1,activation=cos_activation,use_bias=True)
group4 = ycos(group4)
zsin = Dense(1,activation=sin_activation,use_bias=True)
group5 = zsin(group5)
zcos = Dense(1,activation=cos_activation,use_bias=True)
group6 = zcos(group6)
outputTensor = Concatenate()([group1,group2,group3,group4,group5,group6])
```

Connect the custom layer with the Fully-connected-block:

```
block1 = Dense(128,activation='relu',use_bias=True)(outputTensor)
```

create the Fully-connected-block

```
block2 = Dense(128,activation='relu',use_bias=True)(block1)
block3 = Dense(128,activation='relu',use_bias=True)(block2)
block4 = Dense(128,activation='relu',use_bias=True)(block3)
block5 = Dense(128,activation='relu',use_bias=True)(block4)
block6 = Dense(128,activation='relu',use_bias=True)(block5)
block7 = Dense(128,activation='relu',use_bias=True)(block6)
block8 = Dense(128,activation='relu',use_bias=True)(block7)
block9 = Dense(128,activation='relu',use_bias=True)(block8)
block10 = Dense(128,activation='relu',use_bias=True)(block9)
outputamplitude = Dense(1,activation='elu',use_bias=True)(block10)
```

#create the model:

```
model = Model(inputTensor,outputamplitude)
```

custom activation function:

```
# Custom activation function
from keras.layers import Activation
from keras import backend as K
from keras.utils.generic_utils import get_custom_objects

def sin_activation(x):
    return K.sin(x)

def cos_activation(x):
    return K.cos(x)

get_custom_objects().update({'sin_activation': Activation(sin_activation)})
get_custom_objects().update({'cos_activation': Activation(cos_activation)})
```

Comment: how can groupX have an output_shape of (None, 128) in the Lambda layer if inputTensor has shape (None, 3) ?

Comment: @marco I used the example cited in the question. There, the output is 2, so.. The group layer as output (None, 2). Let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: since inputTensor is (None, 3) in your case u will have groupX = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,X], output_shape=((1,)))(inputTensor) ... hovewer u can simply solve all the problems

Comment: I will write it in colab and share here later. thanks

Comment: I did it if u are interested

Comment: yes I am @MarcoCerliani goyes.yesid@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

```
# Custom activation function
from keras.layers import Activation
from keras import backend as K
from keras.utils.generic_utils import get_custom_objects

def sin_activation(x):
    return K.sin(x)

def cos_activation(x):
    return K.cos(x)

get_custom_objects().update({'sin_activation': Activation(sin_activation)})
get_custom_objects().update({'cos_activation': Activation(cos_activation)})
```